# For loops in button arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, button

I have an 42, 5 array of buttons that is up and working, However I cannot seem to make it work in a for loop.

```
for btnarray(1,0) to btnarray(42,0)
'Disable all buttons
next
for btnarray(1,0) to btnarray(1,5)
'Enable buttons
next
```

this just comes up with the error message, 'for' loop variable cannot be type 'system.windows.forms.button' because the type does not support the required operators.
what would be the best work around, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 41
    Dim btn = btnarray(i,0)
    'Disable btn in each iteration'
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To 4
    Dim btn = btnarray(1,i)
    'Enable btn in each iteration'
Next
```

Comment: the code works, however btn.enabled = false comes up with an error what would be the best way to fix that

Comment: never mind after some tinkering found the answer my self.
                  'If btn Is Nothing Then
                    Else : btn.Enabled = False
                    End If' 
if anyone was looking for the answer